# Select item in list returns null on Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I'm here to explain a strange behaviour (in my opinion) occurring in my Xamarin Forms application.

In one of my pages I have a list which is the datasource of a combobox object. This list is correctly populated from a sqlite database and the selected item is retrieved and displayed correctly when the page loads. When I choose to attach a file to the record, I navigate to another page and save the edits, but if I navigate back in iOS the selected item always returns null.

Here's my simple code that selects the item:

Class:

```cs
public class Attributo4 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int IdAttributo { get; set; }
    public string DescAttributo { get; set; }
    public int Ordine { get; set; }
    public bool IsPlaceholder { get; set; }

    public Attributo4()
    {
        Ordine = 1;
        IsPlaceholder = false;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Declaration:

```cs
private List<Attributo4> risposteDettaglioAttributoList4;
public List<Attributo4> RisposteDettaglioAttributoList4
{
    get { return risposteDettaglioAttributoList4; }
    set
    {
        risposteDettaglioAttributoList4 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RisposteDettaglioAttributoList4));
    }
}

private Attributo4 selectedAttributo4;
public Attributo4 SelectedAttributo4
{
    get { return selectedAttributo4; }
    set
    {
        if (selectedAttributo4 != value)
            IsDirty = true;

        selectedAttributo4 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedAttributo4));
    }
}
```

Sample code:

```cs
SelectedAttributo4 = RisposteDettaglioAttributoList4.FirstOrDefault(w => w.IdAttributo == DettaglioAperto.IdRisposteDettaglioAttributo4);
```

If I explore the list and check it against the value of **DettaglioAperto.IdRisposteDettaglioAttributo4** I can find the row and the item, but then the item **SelectedAttributo4** is null. Before this solution I tried a for loop of the list, but the result was the same. In Android and UWP versions of the app the value is correctly retrieved and displayed.

How can I solve my issue?

Comment: you need to provide more than one line of code - there is not enough context here for us to see what you are doing

Comment: Yes Jason, you're right... I realized it yesterday when I was going home... I need holidays...

Comment: Have you made any change to `SelectedAttributo4` during you navigate to another page and come back? Maybe a Minimal, Reproducible Example would make you question clear.